# ReactRouter work not correct, only change url not view

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can’t understand why  does not go to the page, but simply changes the URL.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import classify from 'src/classify'
import defaultClasses from './logo.scss'
import logo from './logo.svg'
class Logo extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.shape({
      wrapper: PropTypes.string,
      logo: PropTypes.string
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, history } = this.props

    return (
      <Link to="/" className={classes.wrapper}>
        <img className={classes.logo} src={logo} height="70"  alt="" title="" />
      </Link>
    )
  }
}

export default classify(defaultClasses)(Logo)
```

there is same with`withRouter() history.push`
The component don't rendering.

In `renderRoutes()` i have next path
    `<Route exact path="/" component={Page} />`

renderRoutes() call from App.js(main)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Page from '../../Page'

import Journey from 'src/components/Journey'

const renderRoutingError = props => <ErrorView {...props} />

const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Page} />
    <Route exact path="/journey/" component={Journey} />
)

export default renderRoutes
```

use Context

```
   this.props.pushContext({
      nav: <Logo />,
      background: 'white'
    })
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for `renderRoutes()` and where you call it?

Comment: Have you created the actual React Router <Route/> anywhere? A <Link/> won't work without a corresponding <Route/>

Comment: @Luze added code

Comment: You should declare <Route exact path="/journey/" component={Journey} /> route first. then  <Route exact path="/" component={Page} /> route.

Comment: Does it even compile without end of switch of statement.

Comment: no, i forgot add end tag after adding to article, in code i have no errors
@KarthikR

Comment: @0x00000228 then the path didnt match. Can you specify the URL which it redirects? Please note that the basename of the router also matters and so specify both.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close your `Switch` component in `renderRoutes`.

```
const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Page} />
    <Route exact path="/journey/" component={Journey} />
  </Switch> <-- You forgot to close your Switch here.
)
```

Comment: no, i forgot add end tag after adding to article, in code i have no errors

Comment: but this Logo.js component located in Context, and not working